# Display all of *mp3 files to web interface with php

Tags: php

As the title above, I want to display all of mp3 files to my page. But, unfortunately it does not show any error as well as the mp3 player on the web. Below is my code for it:

```
<?php
            $files = glob('/images/pic/sound/*.mp3');
                for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
                {
                $num = $files;
                echo date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($num))."<br><br>";
                echo '<audio src="'.$num.'" autostart="true" loop="infinite"></audio>'."<br><br>";

                }


            ?>
```

If I display one file, It does. But when I pull all of it to do, it does not T__T

If you have any solution for it, May you help me to solve it? Thank you for your reading :)

Comment: `$num` is an array, not string. Try `foreach($files as $file) {`.

Comment: as said, $files is not a string, try to print_r it first, before your loop: print_r($files); just after your $files line.

Comment: @chris85 thank you for your advise, I have changed and it does show it out belonged with this error: 
Warning: filemtime() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ender\record.php on line 15
January 01 1970 01:00:00.


Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ender\record.php on line 16

Comment: It have fixed it, It's working now, Thank you so much @chris85

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing [$i] and assigning array to `$num` at first line inside loop. See below:

```
<?php
        $files = glob('/images/pic/sound/*.mp3');
        for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
            $num = $files[$i];
            echo date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($num))."<br><br>";
            echo '<audio src="'.$num.'" autostart="true" loop="infinite"></audio>'."<br><br>";
        }
?>
```